Confusion on calculation of two-sample Anderson-Darling Statistic
In his paper A two-sample Anderson-Darling Rank Statistic, Pettitt states that the two-sample statistic simplifies to: $A_{nm}^2 = \frac{1}{mn}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{(M_iN-ni)^2}{i(N-1)}$ where $N$ is the sum of the sample sizes $n$ and $m$ and where $M_i$ is defined as the number of $X'$s less than or equal to the $i$th smallest in the combined sample.  In the paper, he then provides a table of what I believe are critical values of the statistic at specified significance levels $\alpha$ and specified samples sizes $m$ and $n$.  He then states that the distribution of $A_{nm}^2$ is found by the enumeration of all possible values of $A_{nm}^2$ by considering the $N!/(n!m!)$ orderings of $n$ $X'$s and $m$ $Y'$s.
My questions are the following:

In the table entry for $m=2$ and $n=4$, the paper has that for $\alpha = 0.1$, the nominal critical $A_{\alpha} = 2.250$ so that $pr(A_{nm}^2 \ge A_{\alpha})$ is nearest to $\alpha$.  It also has that $pr(A_{nm}^2 \ge A_{\alpha} = 0.133$.  Is this suggesting that there is no exact critical value for $\alpha = 0.1$?
For $m=2$ and $n=4$, it would seem that one can form the distribution of $A_{nm}^2$ by enumeration of all possible values of $A_{nm}^2$ by considering 15 $(6!/(2!4!))$ orderings of $n$ $X'$s and $m$ $Y'$s.  However, I don't see how the actual values in the sample do not matter.  That is, if sample $n$ was [1,1] and sample $m$ was [2,2,2,2] versus if sample $n$ was [1,2] and sample $m$ was [1,2,3,4], it would seem that the statistic values would be different since $M_i$ directly depends on the ranks of the sample values.  Could someone explain this or point me to what I am missing?
Related to question 2, how exactly is the "ordering" of the sample going to affect the statistic calculation?  The $i$th smallest in the combined sample should remain the $i$th smallest regardless of order, it seems.


Note that the test statistic relies only on the relative order of the values (their ranks). It's discrete. So as with any discrete test statistic, there will in general not be an exact level $\alpha$ test, at least not without introducing randomness, which many people see as undesirable in practice.
